# Monitoring Kubernetes Pods in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring

We have an application deployed on GKE with a total of 10 pods running and serving the application.
I am trying to find the metrics using which I can create an alert when my Pod goes down or is there a way to check the status of Pods so that I can set up an alert based on that condition?

I explored GCP and looked into their documentation but couldn't find anything. What I could find is one metric below but I don't know what it measures.
To me it looks like a number of times Kubernetes thinks a pod has died and it restarts the pod.

```
Metric: kubernetes.io/container/restart_count
Resource type: k8s_container
```

Any advice on this is highly appreciated as we can improve our monitoring based on this metric

[image: GCP alerting policy creation]

Answer (score 2):

That metric is the same you are right it will the count of POD restart.

> Number of times the container has restarted. Sampled every 60 seconds.
> After sampling, data is not visible for up to 120 seconds.

Read more at : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes

**Or**

You can use Prometheus to get the metrics and monitor with **Grafana**

```
sum(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{cluster="$cluster",namespace="$namespace",pod=~"$service.*"})
```

This will give the value of the POD restart count.

**OR**

You can also use the **BotKube** : https://www.botkube.io/installation/

You can set to notify when your readiness liveness fails to slack notification etc..

**Or**

You write your own script and run it on Kubernetes to monitor and notify when any POD restart in cluster.

Example github : https://github.com/harsh4870/Slack-Post-On-POD-Ready-State

This script notifies in slack when POD becomes ready after deployment, you can change it to monitor the restart count.

i would recommend using **Prometheus, Grafana** option, however, **stackdriver** is Good but i am not Google employee.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use this metric on GCP alerting and I am seeing something I have attached to the question. So two things here - 1) Why the restart count is always showing 10 as base? Is it because my cluster has 10 pods running. Ideally restart count should be zero so I am just thinking what should I do for my threshold value. 2) Another thing is does that count at any time signifying that these number of times Kubernetes has restarted the pods?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to monitor when a pod is down? Kubernetes will immediatly try to start it on the same node or on a different one if that node is down for whatever reason.

Instead, there are other metrics you have to monitor for. Like the restart_count which could indicate that pods are not coming back online. But also other metrics like

- kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total
- kube_pod_status_phase
- kube_pod_container_status_running
- kube_pod_status_phase vs kube_node_status_capacity_pods

This article has a lot of interesting metrics to monitor for https://medium.com/google-cloud/gke-monitoring-84170ea44833

Comment: whenever I am trying to use any of these metrics in my alerting policy I am seeing this on the graph - ```No data is available for the selected timeframe``` I tried to increase the timeframe to longer like 90 days but still no data. Is there any filter or advanced setting I need to do?

Comment: Check agent is properly running on your GKE or monitoring is enabled for GKE.